# Composer não instala pacotes

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Recentemente instalei o ubuntu na minha máquina e estou preparando o ambiente para trabalhar com o Laravel. Tudo está funcionado exceto que não consigo criar o projeto Laravel, quando executo comando

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel projeto
```

Ele fica executando infinitamente, e nada acontece. Nenhuma mensagem de erro é exibida, e nada é instalado. Tentei fazer o download do composer novamente e agora ele fica fazendo donwload eterno. Assim que intalei o ubuntu, eu consegui fazer o dowload do composer, logo após isso fiz uma atualização que o ubuntu estava pedindo e então não consigo mais usar o composer, não sei dizer que a atualização é resposável por isso. Agradeço toda a ajuda.

Comment: Quando você baixa o laravel a primeira vez ele cria uma cópia na pasta composer, talvez você tenha instalado em uma pasta inacessivel. Me diga você chegou a tentar o comando artisan ou habilitar ele?

Comment: `sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel projeto`

Comment: sudo não resolve Zoom eu tentei antes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não tentei porque nada foi instalado. E eu tentei instalar outros pacotes com o composer e acontece o mesmo, tentei um self-update e acontece o mesmo, fica executando e não termina nunca.

Comment: Eu cheguei a limpar o cache do composer também e não resolveu, baixei uma versão manual do composer.phar e tentei rodar ela pra baixar os pacotes e não deu certo.

Comment: Perai, mas você esta tentando instalar algo sem instalar o "inicial" ainda? Faz o seguinte só pra ter certeza, use este comando `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projeto`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o problema persiste. O código que usei acima, já havia funcionado outras vezes, eu o peguei no próprio site da Laravel, e em um vídeo da laracast.

Comment: Já tentou instalar em outro diretório ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

o problema aqui descrito é referente a IPv6, basta desabilita-lo, ou dar maior prescedencia ao Ipv4 para que volte a funcionar. Para o Ubuntu 14.04 utilize o seguinte comando.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"
```

Para maiores informações visitem o link:
[getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md)

Comment: Ótima resposta +1

Answer (score 2):

Quando você cria um projeto o Laravel já deve estar instalado, provavelmente você não rodou o Installer, faça isto primeiro de tudo:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Depois tente criar um projeto usando exatamente este comando com `--prefer-dist`:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projeto
```

### Reinstalar o composer

Recomendo que tente desinstalar o composer se os comando não funcionarem, pra isto delete o `composer.phar` e remova o `/home/<user>/.composer`.

E depois reinstale:

```
curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54287/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-composer-nao-instala-pacotes)

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente o composer está tentando instalar tudo, mas sua internet está lenta, e ai ele está demorando para baixar todos os pacotes.

Roda o comando com `-vvv` para ver o que está acontecendo: `composer create-project laravel/laravel projeto -vvv`

Comment: Minha internet é de 20mb, não acredito que seja problema com a conexão.

Comment: As vezes a internet fica lenta. As vezes é problema com o GitHub. Mesmo assim, tenta rodar o comando com `-vvv` como eu falei. Ele vai te dar um log do que está acontecendo, e ai fica mais fácil de descobrir o problema.

Comment: @FReNeTiC achei legal o comando `-vvv`, só uma dica, pra você enviar uma mensagem pra um usuário tem que usar o `@nome do usuário`, note que ele tem que estar participando da pergunta, com comentários ou respostas ou perguntas.

Comment: @FReNeTiC não consegui rodar o comando porque removi o composer, fazendo os testes da conversa anterior. Vou baixar um composer versão manual e testar o que vc recomendou.

Comment: Checking CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json

Fica neste ponto.

Comment: @ZiruZanrgeiff a data e hora do OS estão certos?

Comment: Sim está correto. Tanto data como hora. No time zone de São Paulo.

Comment: Eu não negativei, na verdade eu não entendi os negativos, me parece uma boa dica, no entanto acho que o motivo foi porque não é uma resposta conclusiva para o problema, mas não sei dizer se foi isso mesmo. Talvez você poderia transformar em comentário.